# Something In My Code Is Ignoring Everything After The Ampersand

Tags: javascript, php

I can't for the life of me figure out what in this code is getting rid of the &. If someone enters a URL like `http://example.com/?ref=me&id=1` I need the whole URL to show up in the echo. But it's cutting off everything after the &.

Here is the code that's being used.

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar">
Enter the site URL that people will go to when they click your banner and click update to store it:<br> 
<input id="ban<?php echo $key;?>" type="text" value="" size="100">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" class="buttonHAdd" value="Update" onclick="updateBannerURL(&#39;<?php echo $directoryfile ;?>&#39;, &#39;ban<?php echo $key;?>&#39;)"><br>
Use the following HTML to display the banner on your site:<br><span id="htmlban<?php echo $key;?>" style="background-color: #ffffff"></span>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function updateBannerURL(bannerFile, id) {

if($("#"+id).val() == "") {
  alert("You have not entered a site url");
  return;
 }
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update.banner.php",
    data:'m='+$('#memberId').val()+'&b='+bannerFile+'&u='+$("#"+id).val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        $('#html'+id).text(data.bannerHtml);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       $('.workareaTip').html('Hmm... Looks like an error occurred.');
   }
   });
}
```

PHP File update.banner.php

```
<?php 
$domain = 'https://example.com/banner';
$u = $_POST['u'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$m = $_POST['m'];
$array = array('bannerHtml'=>
    '<a href="'.$u.'"><img src="'.$domain.'/banners/'.$m.'/'.$b.'" border=""/><a/>'
    );
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

With that code, I can enter in: `http://example.com/?ref=me&id=1` and here is what it echos back: `http://example.com/?ref=me` totally ignoring everything after the ampersand.

Comment: I suggest to you use `data: { m: $('#memberId').val(), b: bannerFile, u: $("#"+id).val() }` on post request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to encode the data you are sending using `encodeURI()` on each variable, or just pass the data properly:

```
data: {
    m: $('#memberId').val(),
    b: bannerFile,
    u: $("#"+id).val()
},
```

Comment: I don't know why that works but it does lol. Thank you so much @Enstage

Comment: It works because the way you were manually doing it before, neither javascript or PHP could tell whether the `&` was a new variable or part of the string, by doing it the way I have, Javascript encodes the ampersand so it parsed as part of the string.

Also, if my answer is correct, select the green tick under the voting arrows to mark it as such.

Comment: Awesome. I did check the green tick. I would have before you wrote this but it made me wait 6 minutes lol. Anyway, thank you so much!